# How can I create a List of items from the API data I get?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to create a list of subcategories that I'm getting from the API and display them in the App. The problem is that I don't know how to transform the items from the Array (API) into List items.

```
componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('/categories/' + this.props.match.params.id)
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data.children) //Array of strings

          }) 
  }

 render(){

      return(
          <div className={classes.Showcategory}>
              <h1>{this.props.match.params.id}</h1>
              <li>Here I need for each string of the array a list item<li/>
          </div>
      );
  }
```

Comment: store the response in an array managed by state and then return it using `Array.map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a state variable for the component. When you are making a request, update the state. When state gets update your component will be re rendered, with the data you want.

Try this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    categories: []
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get("/categories/" + this.props.match.params.id).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.children); //Array of strings
    this.setState({ categories: response.data.children });
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className={classes.Showcategory}>
      <h1>{this.props.match.params.id}</h1>
      {this.state.categories.map((category, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{category}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that [React recommends that you don't use `index` as the `key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). For your case, if `category` strings are unique, use those instead.